# Angular 6 - Unable to Convert Base64 to PDF

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, base64

I'm attempting to convert a Base64 string to PDF and download it in the browser, and the generated PDF is not readable:

app.component.html ->

```
<div style="text-align:center">
  <form>
    <div class="form-row text-center">
      <button type="button" class="btn div-button" (click)="showPdf()">PDF</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

app.component.ts ->

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  showPdf() {
    const pdfInBase64 = '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\n';
    const newBlob = new Blob([pdfInBase64], {type: 'application/pdf'});
    if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
      window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(newBlob); // For IE browser
    }
    const linkElement = document.createElement('a');
    const url = URL.createObjectURL(newBlob);
    linkElement.setAttribute('href', url);
    linkElement.setAttribute('download', 'sample.pdf');
    const clickEvent = new MouseEvent('click', {
      'view': window,
      'bubbles': true,
     'cancelable': false
    });
    linkElement.dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
  }
}
```

The PDF gets downloaded in the browser. However, it's not readable.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem is that you are not decoding your base 64 PDF, use the function `atob()` to achieve this:

```
var pdfInBase64 = atob(
  'JVBERi0xLjcKCjEgMCBvYmogICUgZW50cnkgcG9pbnQKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvQ2F0YWxvZwog' +
  'IC9QYWdlcyAyIDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjIgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvUGFnZXMKICAv' +
  'TWVkaWFCb3ggWyAwIDAgMjAwIDIwMCBdCiAgL0NvdW50IDEKICAvS2lkcyBbIDMgMCBSIF0K' +
  'Pj4KZW5kb2JqCgozIDAgb2JqCjw8CiAgL1R5cGUgL1BhZ2UKICAvUGFyZW50IDIgMCBSCiAg' +
  'L1Jlc291cmNlcyA8PAogICAgL0ZvbnQgPDwKICAgICAgL0YxIDQgMCBSIAogICAgPj4KICA+' +
  'PgogIC9Db250ZW50cyA1IDAgUgo+PgplbmRvYmoKCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwKICAvVHlwZSAvRm9u' +
  'dAogIC9TdWJ0eXBlIC9UeXBlMQogIC9CYXNlRm9udCAvVGltZXMtUm9tYW4KPj4KZW5kb2Jq' +
  'Cgo1IDAgb2JqICAlIHBhZ2UgY29udGVudAo8PAogIC9MZW5ndGggNDQKPj4Kc3RyZWFtCkJU' +
  'CjcwIDUwIFRECi9GMSAxMiBUZgooSGVsbG8sIHdvcmxkISkgVGoKRVQKZW5kc3RyZWFtCmVu' +
  'ZG9iagoKeHJlZgowIDYKMDAwMDAwMDAwMCA2NTUzNSBmIAowMDAwMDAwMDEwIDAwMDAwIG4g' +
  'CjAwMDAwMDAwNzkgMDAwMDAgbiAKMDAwMDAwMDE3MyAwMDAwMCBuIAowMDAwMDAwMzAxIDAw' +
  'MDAwIG4gCjAwMDAwMDAzODAgMDAwMDAgbiAKdHJhaWxlcgo8PAogIC9TaXplIDYKICAvUm9v' +
  'dCAxIDAgUgo+PgpzdGFydHhyZWYKNDkyCiUlRU9G');
```

Answer (score 42):

You can use this code in the showPdf function to generate the PDF, Hope this helps

```
showPdf() {
        const linkSource = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + '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\n';
        const downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
        const fileName = "sample.pdf";

        downloadLink.href = linkSource;
        downloadLink.download = fileName;
        downloadLink.click();
    }
```

Comment: Hi Sachi. The PDF gets auto downloaded in a Chrome Browser. However, nothing happens on an IE browser. There are no error messages either. I'm working on Angular 6. Hence, I un-commented all the entries in pollyfills.ts. Yet, it doesn't work.

Comment: How could i make this pdf viewable on my UI template as a section, as in on click of a button the pdf is generated and then made viewable

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) to download image as pdf. I use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) to generate my base64image.

```
var pdf = new jspdf("l", "mm", [288, 288]);


 pdf.addImage(
    base64String,
    "PNG",
    0,
    position,
    imageWidth,
    imgHeight
   );
  pdf.save("cv.pdf"); // download PDF
```